# Facebook Post Approval in group

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can I check **Post Approval** in group

> All group posts must be approved by an admin or a moderator.

is checked or not by access_token or something else

Comment: Don’t think that info is available via API.

Comment: I apologise for the delay in replying to your comment. Do you know another way to get that info?

Comment: No. What would you need this info for?